STM32F4 SPI Communication Issue with RA8875 Display Controller
I'm trying to port Adafruit's RA8875 Arduino library to work with an STM32F4 Discovery board. The SPI communication is failing during device initialization.
During initialization, when reading the device ID register (0x0), I expect to read 0x75 but always get 0xFF. The SPI DR register gets set to 0xFF on the first transfer and never changes.
You can also see on the Logic Analyzer Output that the MOSI line is generated as expected but there is no response on the MISO line.

Is my SPI configuration correct for the RA8875 (Mode 3, ~1.3MHz)? Is there anything else I need to configure?
Could the issue be with the SPI transfer implementation?
Are there any timing requirements between CS toggles and data transfers for RA8875 that is missing?

Hardware setup:

STM32F4 Discovery Board
Adafruit RA8875 Display Controller
SPI1:

SCK: PA5
MISO: PA6
MOSI: PA7
CS: PA4
RST: PB0


Designated L8705 power supply for MCU and RA8875

I've tried various SPI modes and baud rates as well as adding delays between transfers and confirmed the wire connections are correct.

Source Code
SPI configuration
 static SPI_Config getSPIConfig(void)
  {
    return {
      .SPI_DeviceMode = DEVICE_MODE_MASTER,
      .SPI_Mode = SPI_MODE_3,
      .SPI_BaudRate = BR_DIV32,
      .SPIx = SPI1
    };
  }

SPI::SPI(const SPI_Config &config):
    _pSPIx(config.SPIx),
    // Initialize GPIO pins based on which SPI peripheral is being used
    _sck((config.SPIx == SPI1) ? GPIOA : (config.SPIx == SPI2) ? GPIOB : GPIOC,
         (config.SPIx == SPI1) ? GPIO_PIN_5 : (config.SPIx == SPI2) ? GPIO_PIN_13 : GPIO_PIN_10,
         (config.SPIx == SPI3) ? AF_MODE_SPI_3 : AF_MODE_SPI_1_2,
         NO_PULL),
    _miso((config.SPIx == SPI1) ? GPIOA : (config.SPIx == SPI2) ? GPIOB : GPIOC,
          (config.SPIx == SPI1) ? GPIO_PIN_6 : (config.SPIx == SPI2) ? GPIO_PIN_14 : GPIO_PIN_11,
          (config.SPIx == SPI3) ? AF_MODE_SPI_3 : AF_MODE_SPI_1_2,
          NO_PULL),
    _mosi((config.SPIx == SPI1) ? GPIOA : (config.SPIx == SPI2) ? GPIOB : GPIOC,
          (config.SPIx == SPI1) ? GPIO_PIN_7 : (config.SPIx == SPI2) ? GPIO_PIN_15 : GPIO_PIN_12,
          (config.SPIx == SPI3) ? AF_MODE_SPI_3 : AF_MODE_SPI_1_2,
          NO_PULL)
{
    init(config);
}

void SPI::init(const SPI_Config &config) {
    SPI_InitTypeDef _spiInit;

     // Set device mode (Master/Slave)
    _spiInit.Mode = (config.SPI_DeviceMode == DEVICE_MODE_MASTER) ? 
                    SPI_MODE_MASTER : SPI_MODE_SLAVE;
    
    // Set clock polarity and phase based on SPI mode
    switch(config.SPI_Mode) {
        case SPI_MODE_0:
            _spiInit.CLKPolarity = SPI_POLARITY_LOW;
            _spiInit.CLKPhase = SPI_PHASE_1EDGE;
            break;
        case SPI_MODE_1:
            _spiInit.CLKPolarity = SPI_POLARITY_LOW;
            _spiInit.CLKPhase = SPI_PHASE_2EDGE;
            break;
        case SPI_MODE_2:
            _spiInit.CLKPolarity = SPI_POLARITY_HIGH;
            _spiInit.CLKPhase = SPI_PHASE_1EDGE;
            break;
        case SPI_MODE_3:
            _spiInit.CLKPolarity = SPI_POLARITY_HIGH;
            _spiInit.CLKPhase = SPI_PHASE_2EDGE;
            break;
    }
    
    // Set baud rate
    switch(config.SPI_BaudRate) {
        case BR_DIV2:   _spiInit.BaudRatePrescaler = SPI_BAUDRATEPRESCALER_2;   break;
        case BR_DIV4:   _spiInit.BaudRatePrescaler = SPI_BAUDRATEPRESCALER_4;   break;
        case BR_DIV8:   _spiInit.BaudRatePrescaler = SPI_BAUDRATEPRESCALER_8;   break;
        case BR_DIV16:  _spiInit.BaudRatePrescaler = SPI_BAUDRATEPRESCALER_16;  break;
        case BR_DIV32:  _spiInit.BaudRatePrescaler = SPI_BAUDRATEPRESCALER_32;  break;
        case BR_DIV64:  _spiInit.BaudRatePrescaler = SPI_BAUDRATEPRESCALER_64;  break;
        case BR_DIV128: _spiInit.BaudRatePrescaler = SPI_BAUDRATEPRESCALER_128; break;
        case BR_DIV256: _spiInit.BaudRatePrescaler = SPI_BAUDRATEPRESCALER_256; break;
    }

    _spiInit.Direction = SPI_DIRECTION_2LINES; // full-duplex
    _spiInit.DataSize = SPI_DATASIZE_8BIT;
    _spiInit.NSS = SPI_NSS_SOFT;
    _spiInit.FirstBit = SPI_FIRSTBIT_MSB;

    _pSPIx = config.SPIx;
    _spiHandle.Instance = _pSPIx;
    _spiHandle.Init = _spiInit;

    configureClock();

    // Initialize SPI using HAL
    if(HAL_SPI_Init(&_spiHandle) != HAL_OK) {
        Error_Handler();
    }
}

RA8875 initialization sequence
bool Adafruit_RA8875::begin(enum RA8875sizes s) {
  //....

  // Initialize CS and RST pins as outputs
  _cs.init(PP_OUTPUT_MODE, NO_PULL);
  _rst.init(PP_OUTPUT_MODE, NO_PULL);

  // write CS high and keep it high
  _cs.write(GPIO_PIN_SET);

  // write RST low then high
  _rst.write(GPIO_PIN_RESET);
  HAL_Delay(100);
  _rst.write(GPIO_PIN_SET);
  HAL_Delay(100);

  // Initialize SPI
  _spi.begin();

  uint8_t x = readReg(0);
  if (x != 0x75) {
    Error_Handler();  // This is where failure happens
    return false;
  }

  initialize();

  return true;
}

SPI transfers
void Adafruit_RA8875::writeReg(uint8_t reg, uint8_t val) {
  writeCommand(reg);
  writeData(val);
}

uint8_t Adafruit_RA8875::readReg(uint8_t reg) {
  writeCommand(reg);
  return readData();
}

uint8_t Adafruit_RA8875::readData(void) {
  _cs.write(GPIO_PIN_RESET);
  _spi.begin();
  _spi.transfer(RA8875_DATAREAD);
  uint8_t x = _spi.transfer(0x0);
  _spi.end();
  _cs.write(GPIO_PIN_SET);
  return x;
}

void Adafruit_RA8875::writeCommand(uint8_t d) {
  _cs.write(GPIO_PIN_RESET);
  _spi.begin();
  _spi.transfer(RA8875_CMDWRITE);
  _spi.transfer(d);
  _spi.end();
  _cs.write(GPIO_PIN_SET);
}

uint8_t SPI::transfer(uint8_t data) {
    // Wait until TXE is set (Transmit buffer empty)
    while (!(_pSPIx->SR & SPI_SR_TXE));
    
    // Send data
    _pSPIx->DR = data;
    
    // Wait until RXNE is set (Receive buffer not empty)
    while (!(_pSPIx->SR & SPI_SR_RXNE));
    
    // Return received data
    return _pSPIx->DR;
}

void SPI::begin(void) {
    _pSPIx->CR1 |= SPI_CR1_SPE;
}

void SPI::end(void) {
    while (_pSPIx->SR & SPI_SR_BSY);  // Wait until not busy
    _pSPIx->CR1 &= ~SPI_CR1_SPE;
}


It's unclear what libraries you are using. For example, there is no code whatsoever to initialize the SPI peripheral. You are just presenting a function to return a struct of SPI configuration, but is it ever used?

@Justme I added the SPI constructor which shows how the struct is passed to the initialization. I have posted the full code here https://community.st.com/t5/stm32-mcus-products/stm32f4-spi-communication-issue-with-ra8875-display-controller/m-p/753363#M268612

@hcheung I would prefer not to use Arduino code since it needs to integrate into my existing STM projects which are written in STM32Cube with integrated c/cpp

@hcheung SPI::begin() and SPI::end() is used instead of SPI.beginTransaction() and SPI.endTransaction()

If you are using the SPI HAL anyway, why not use it for sendind/receiving data as well? Have you initialized the GPIO pins to alternate function of SPI? Why not let CubeMX initialize everything for you? Usually it lets you to spend time on making the application work, instead of focusing on the details how to make SPI work.

@hcheung the SPI::init(const SPI_Config &config) function called from the constructor initializes SPI communication. Is there something wrong with my initialization? Even if something was wrong I would expect to see something other than always 0xFF.

You are showing a bunch of methods that belong to two Class objects, and Adafruit_RA8875 is obvious the one using an spi instance, but based on all the code fragments you shown, I have no idea how you pass the SPI instance to the Adafruit_RA8875 object. i.e. how the _spi in the object is initialised? Maybe you should show your complete code, that way we know how your code is glue/stitched together.

@hcheung, I put it up on GitHub if you'd like to take a look
https://github.com/Jacob-Mattiq/Adafruit_RA8875/tree/main/RA8875_touchscreen/Core

@jlaufer I asked before if you ever initialized the GPIO pins and you are not doing that.

You never enable the GPIOA clock and config the pins used for SPI1 to push pull and to alternative function, so your SPI construct and SPI.init() are incomplete. This also means that you probably never test the SPI Class alone to make sure it work before writing another Class to use it. Here is my suggestion, 1) use HAL, so that it will configure the GPIO and SPI correctly with MX_GPIO_Init() and MX_SPI1_Init(). 2) if still want to do everything yourself, then generate the code using CubeMX and take a look at the HAL_SPI_MspInit() function in stm32f4xx_hal_msp.c to see what your missing.

@Justme thanks, I will make sure to correctly configure the GPIO pins and if that still doesn't work I will start over from a pure MX project. For the record I have done a lot of industrial work using the UART peripheral to communicate to a computer in the past but now have several use cases where a fully embedded solution is preferred. I have gotten SPI to work before but with a simple sensor in c so I was just copying and pasting code from that - clearly this is a step up from what I typically do.

@hcheung you did see the GPIO.cpp class which calls __HAL_RCC_GPIOA_CLK_ENABLE() and  gpiopininit.Mode = GPIO_MODE_AF_PP; gpiopininit.Alternate = GPIO_AF5_SPI1; ? Each pin in SPI is initialized through the GPIO class.

@jlaufer,  this will be my last comment on this post. Yes, you have a GPIO Class, but does SPI.init() (or anywhere in the code) use the GPIO class to setup the pins? As said before, test SPI Class separately, the rest of code doesn't matter until SPI is working.

@hcheung Yes, it certainly does. And agreed - which is why my question says "SPI Communication Issue" in the title.

Modern MCUs are complex.
You cannot simply go and start using SPI, without configuring the GPIO pins to have the alternate function of being SPI.
Which means you need to enable system/peripheral clocks to all peripherals you intend to use, including GPIO.
Please use a CubeMX project where you use SPI as a base for investigating what subsystems it enables and how it configures them. If you simply try reading the manual and try figuring out what to do in which order and how to do it it may take days, if this is not a simple case of just not enabling clocks to GPIOA, SPI, AFIO mux and configuring GPIOA pins to alt mode.
Basically, the project of blindly trying to communicate with a display is too big task if you are just starting out. Take intermediate steps like can you even toggle a LED, will it toggle at correct speed, to see you can use GPIO at all and the CPU is set to run at correct speed with internal PLLs etc. Then try enabling the SPI, also verifying with tools like oscilloscope, logic analyzer or LEDs that the pins really do something when you try to transfer SPI bytes.

Actually 2 pins were switched in the code.
